# Checking data in form for client and getting errors on checks for it

Tags: php

```
<?php
$Page = new PaginationDisplayInlineBottomAndTopDivs($number, $box, $errors, $go);
   if(form != null) {
    echo "didntfail";
} if (form != 3) {
    echo "failedpasswordsdidntmatch"
} if (form != 4) {
    echo "failedbutdidntgetpasswordrightwithusername";
} if (form != 6) {
    $Display->new FormErrorInputRedBoxShowDisplay($x, $a, $h, $g);
    $inputs = $Page->$Display->setFormInlineWithBox();
}

?>
```

I'm getting an error on line 5.  I'm confused and new to Php.

Comment: add semicolon on line 5

Comment: I am confused, How questions like this don't get downvoted. And a few good questions will get downvoted saying "Low quality". Huhh.. This community needs a boost up!!!!!

Answer (score 2):

```
$Page = new PaginationDisplayInlineBottomAndTopDivs($number, $box, $errors, $go);
   if(form != null) {
    echo "didntfail";
} if (form != 3) {
    echo "failedpasswordsdidntmatch";
} if (form != 4) {
    echo "failedbutdidntgetpasswordrightwithusername";
} if (form != 6) {
    $Display->new FormErrorInputRedBoxShowDisplay($x, $a, $h, $g);
    $inputs = $Page->$Display->setFormInlineWithBox();
}
```

You missed ';' in the line